# Is there a synonym for a decision that has 3 options? How about 4 options?

Tags: synonyms

Hi I am looking for a word or phrase that suggests there are three options, and maybe a word that means there are 4 options. Something that can be used in writing rather than conversation.

Comment: Three way decision

Comment: Thanks. But three-way decision sounds like there are three parties that have to decide on something rather than there are three options to pick from

Comment: Do dilemma, trilemma and quadrilemma suit for quandaries with two, three and four options respectively?

Comment: "Trilemma" is not in use, but I suspect it has a chance of being understood. "Quadrilemma" would probably throw most people for a loop unless they had just been introduced to its narrower cousins.

Comment: Trilemma might work, but I was hoping for something more main-stream. Dilemma just doesn't sound right to me if there are more than two choices.